# Where is model number on Yamaha 9.9 4-stroke outboard motor?

Tags: boat, outboard

I recently purchased a used boat with a Yamaha 9.9 4-stroke outboard motor.

[image]

[image]

I’ve tried looking for the model number so that I can buy replacement parts (someone told me I should have a replacement shear pin on hand).

But I haven’t found the model number yet. Where can I find it on the motor?

*The previous owner can’t recall what the model number is or where on the motor it’s written.*

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, the ID plate with model number, model name and serial number is located here:

[image: e]

The model number is in the upper left corner of this plate, the corner that looks like it's covered in gray paint on your motor.

[image: e]

The manual is available online via your favorite search engine.

Comment: You sure you've got the right thing circled? Looking at the image, there's nothing there. You sure you weren't aiming for the tag to the 4 o'clock of the circle?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yep, if you magnify it till it's pixelated, you'll see a light colored rectangle with the left half of it covered in gray paint. This is the location illustrated in the manual's diagram. The gray paint covers the data that the OP was looking for, which is why the OP didn't see it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Added enlarged image.

Comment: Okay, I'll admit there is something there, but I still don't think it's what you are saying it is. Blow up [the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22DCb.jpg). It shows that area plainly.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yeah, what gives? In the second image it looks like a name plate *used to* be there, where the manual says it belongs. If that's the case, the OP may have second thoughts about keeping this motor. In some jurisdictions, including where I live, mere possession of an article with a missing or defaced serial number tag is a criminal offense if the article left the factory with a tag in place. Not just firearms, it applies to any item of merchandise. That's supposed to cut down on trafficking in stolen goods.

Comment: I would lay money the serial number is on the other tag down the side (the *obvious* tag, lol).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 You're on! Let's see what User1974 says!

Answer (score 1):

The silver tag on the transom mount, visible in the photo, is likely a stamped metal tag with your serial number.  The tag should either mention the model, or the model will be encoded into the serial.

If that tag isn't it then there should be one, very similar in size, location, and appearance.